# Error when installing QAD plugin: Plugin 'qad' could not be loaded due to an error calling its method classFactory()

Tags: qgis-plugins, plugins, windows-10, attributeerror

I am trying to install the QAD plugin and it appears this error:

```
No se pudo cargar el complemento 'qad' debido a un error al llamar a su método classFactory() 

AttributeError: 'QVariant' object has no attribute 'split' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.10/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 334, in _startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "C:/Users/Magdalena/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qad\__init__.py", line 29, in classFactory
    return Qad(iface)
  File "C:/Users/Magdalena/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qad\qad.py", line 409, in __init__
    userLocaleList = QSettings().value("locale/userLocale").split("_")
AttributeError: 'QVariant' object has no attribute 'split'


Versión de Python: 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] 
Versión de QGIS: 3.10.13-A Coruña A Coruña, 311f3bbade
```

Someone knows how can I fix it? I have Windows 10 Pro.

---

I do not know whether it is related, but when I reinitiate QGIS the QAD plugin started to work (at least I can see the tools). However, I have another problem now. It is not possible to use any of the plugin's tools, because it does not recognise the layers that I need to edit. In the command, it says that the SRC must be a reproject SRC. I did it, but the problem persists.

Comment: Have you checked with the plugin's website and bug reports? If so, what did your research yield?

Comment: Yes, but there are not reports about this bug specifically. On the website, only 3 issues have been reported (not this one).

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  With your original problem resolved, and a new one having emerged, I think your question would now benefit from being heavily revised to try and make what you are currently asking clearer.  I recommend reviewing http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115 for tips on how to structure a good question.